# Jenkins : How to add custom tool to my job's build environment

Tags: jenkins, customtool

I define a custom tool in Jenkins and I would like to run it during a build. 
In "https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Custom+Tools+Plugin" I see the following :
"Then, you just need to add the tool requirement to your job's Build Environment" but I cannot find such an option anywhere. Where can I find it? Or is there another way to run the installation of the custom tool?

Answer (score 3):

Is this a Pipeline? If it is, you can include it in the pipeline file under 'environment', prior to the stages, like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    timestamps()
  }
  environment {
      TOOL = tool name: '<tool>', type:     'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'
  }
  stages {
...
}
```

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: Invalid option type "timestamps". Valid option types: [ansiColor, authorizationMatrix, buildDiscarder, catchError, checkoutToSubdirectory, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, durabilityHint, lock, newContainerPerStage, overrideIndexTriggers, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, preserveStashes, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, retry, script, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, timeout, waitUntil, warnError, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, ws] @ line 5, column 9.
           timestamps()

Comment: removed options part, then still get "ERROR: No com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool named <tool> found"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scripted pipelines you can add a tool using the 'tool' command. 
The following example is to add a custom tool to a scripted pipeline. The tool must already be defined through the custom-tool-plugin in your global jenkins administration.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('windows') {
    stage ('prepare env ') {
       withEnv(["MY_TOOL_DIR=${tool name: 'my_tool', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'}"]){

        echo "Path to my_tool\"${MY_TOOL_DIR}\""
        bat( script: '@"%MY_TOOL_DIR%\\my_tool.exe",
             returnStdout: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid tool setup if it has been done already? @Markus Hofsetter

Comment: Tool Setup is managed by the custom tool plugin. So you can add a some code that checks if your tool is already installed in the global jenkins administration.

For example you could do 

`if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
    exit 0
fi`

$FILE could be the tool itself or some marker file that you create the first time that the tool is installed.

Answer (score -1):

In your project configuration (`/job/<your-project>/configure`), in the Build Environment area, there's an option to "Install custom tools".  Check this and you can choose from the tools you've configured in the Global Tool Configuration (`/configureTools/`), and if you specified a script it will be run at the start of your build to install the tool.

[image]

In this example I've chosen to add the clojure tool i've configured to the build.

Comment: Are you sure this is available for pipeline jobs? I do not see a Build Environment section. This only appears to exist for standard GUI jobs. On my end I only see General, Office 365, Build Triggers, Advanced Proj. Options, and Pipeline.

Comment: Not sure I’m afraid, maybe @sean-c answer will help?

Comment: @Conan How do we access the `clojure` variable in the build step?

Comment: I think we just call it from a shell, I'm afraid we've stopped using jenkins now so I can't check.  Good luck!